# How do I add an integer to an attribute using a form in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, update-attributes

I have a form that takes in an integer for a user attribute called `calories:` and I want the input integer to be added to the current value, not replace it. So my question is basically: how do I take the form input value and use it to increase the number of calories?

Ok so here is the form in my users/show view:

`<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label "Add calories" %>
          <%= f.number_field :calories, class: 'form-control'%>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.submit "Add", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>`

and my update action in my users_controller:

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  @user.assign_attributes(user_params)
end
```

`private`

`def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:calories)
  end`

Comment: Please share some code...

Comment: could you show update code from controller and form code from view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So presumably you have an @user object and a params[:calories] value(Your names may be different). In your update action you will do this:

```
previous_calories = @user.calories
final_calories = previous_calories + params[:calories]
@user.update_attributes(calories: final_calories)
```

That is how to do it on a high level.  I would actually extract this into a model method on user like this:

```
def update_calories(calories)
  previous_calories = self.calories
  total_calories = previous_calories + calories
  self.update_attribute(calories: total_calories)
end
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for. So I tried that first bit of code in my update action and I got this error when I tried to add calories. "nil can't be coerced into Fixnum" for line `final_calories = previous_calories + params[:calories]`

Comment: That means either your params[:calories] are nil or your self.calories is nil.  Your form looks good so I am going to assume the later.  You can change `previous_calories = self.calories` to `previous_calories = self.calories || 0` which should get rid of the error if your params are correct.  As Eric as suggested below it may be a good idea to initialize calories with a default value of 0 in which case you wouldn't need the code above.

Comment: Ah, so the problem I was having was with the params. I needed to add `[:user]`. And now it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you will ALWAYS be adding the new value of calories to the persisted value of calories, you could override the setter in the User model to perform this when the User record is saved.

```
def calories=(value)
  self[:calories] += value
end
```

I am assuming that you set a default to calories in the migration?

```
t.integer :calories, default: 0
```

Every time you set a User's calories, it will add the value it was set to... to the persisted value...

[image]